# Switch Stack 9300 family

Tags: cisco-catalyst

Can I stack 9300X with C9300-48P? I have a site that need to use 18 spf port and 48 copper port so i don't need them to purchase 3 switches C9300-48 ports to get 18 ports that will be expensive so i was thinking to go with C9300X, but it should stack to C9300-48P for redundancy.

Answer (score 3):

Quoting from

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/switches/catalyst-9300-series-switches/nb-06-cat9300-ser-data-sheet-cte-en.html

> **Mixed Stacking with Backward Compatibility** – Stack your Catalyst 9300X fiber switches with Catalyst 9300 and Catalyst 9300X
> Multigigabit switches, bringing stackable high-speed fiber to the
> access

However, there's a few caveats w/regards to licencing levels. The section *Stacking* in the above document has the details.

If *many SFP slots* is what you're after, there's SFP-only models in both the C9300X and C9300 range.